# React Native: I want the app to navigate to "Home" after someone signed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

I want my app to navigate home after someone signed in, but it don't work it is because the roots didn't update. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW4LS.png) the App code to understand what I want to say.

Which is the best way to handle this in React Native?

- to give up the ternary operator
- to refresh the page after someone logged in(I saw that the manual refresh push to home, but I don't know how to force refresh with navigation)

Comment: if isSignedIn is a state in your redux or hook context, you should dispatch an action after user login successfully ( onPress=()=>Login().then( dispatch(setSignedIn(true) )  ) then it automaticallt shows home screen

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

First we'll need to create a context for auth where we can expose necessary methods:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

So our component will look like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default function App({ navigation }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: true,
            userToken: null,
          };
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      userToken: null,
    }
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;

      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch (e) {
      }
      dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  const authContext = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async data => {
        //call Api    
        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
      signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
      signUp: async data => {
        //call Api 
        dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {state.userToken == null ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and your SignIn screen:

```
function SignInScreen() {
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={setUsername}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button title="Sign in" onPress={() => signIn({ username, password })} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was my first time when I worked with other hooks than useEffect and useState, but after several hours I finally got it done. :)

Answer (score 0):

have you read this doc about it?
[RN navigation auth flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#define-our-screens)

- SplashScreen - This will show a splash or loading screen when we're restoring the token.
- SignInScreen - This is the screen we show if the user isn't signed in already (we couldn't find a token).
- HomeScreen - This is the screen we show if the user is already signed in.

Code

```
if (state.isLoading) {
  // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
  return <SplashScreen />;
}

return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    {state.userToken == null ? (
      // No token found, user isn't signed in
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignInScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Sign in',
          // When logging out, a pop animation feels intuitive
          // You can remove this if you want the default 'push' animation
          animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
        }}
      />
    ) : (
      // User is signed in
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    )}
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

ps. Please let me know if it helps you ‍♂️

Comment: I used the instruction from the upper comment. It was based on the docs to, so it worked. Thanks for help.